# jCarousel, Counter, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, jcarousel

Im using this plugin: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

I want there do be a counter that can display: 
1 of 4

When clicking the next button, it should say: 
2 of 4 and so on...

The script is the default initialization:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();

                        </script>
```

However, haven't seen an example of this in the documentation ? So any help would be appreciated...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nmrElements = $('#mycarousel').children('li').length;

    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        scroll: 1,
        itemLoadCallback: function (instance, controlElement) {
            if (instance.first != undefined) {
                $('#label').html(instance.first + ' of ' + nmrElements);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `id`-s to each image in carousel. And add some javascript to write the number from `id` of that images.

And also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Callback_function(elem) {
    document.write(this.id);    
}

jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    initCallback: Callback_function,
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite like that - I dont want it to scroll 2 pictures at a time... I would like a counter, like a kindda paging function...

Answer (score 0):

Should be kind of impossible to realize with what is given there. Since it's just a `ul` that is hidden behind a div and only that `ul` element gets scrolled when you click on a button.

There is no semantic property that you could use to identify the currently visible object.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
            // alert(this.mycarousel);   
            // alert("inside carousel");
            // Disable autoscrolling if
            // the user clicks the prev
            // or next button.
            carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
                carousel.startAuto(0);
            });

            // Pause autoscrolling if
            // the user moves with the
            // cursor over the clip.
            carousel.clip.hover(
                function() {
                    carousel.stopAuto();
                },
                function() {
                    carousel.startAuto();
            });
        }

        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
            auto : 2,
            scroll : 1,
            wrap : 'last',
            initCallback : mycarousel_initCallback,
            itemFallbackDimension: 300,
            //size: mycarousel_itemList.length, 
            itemFirstInCallback:mycarousel_itemFirstInCallback 
            // itemLoadCallback: { onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback} 
        });
    });

    $(".jcarousel-prev").after("<div><h6 id=\"myHeader\" style=\"color:#FFFFFF;width:68%; top:85%; left:40px;font-size:100%; display: block;\" class=\"counterL\"></h6></div>");

    function display(s) { 
        $('#myHeader').html(s); 
    }; 

    function mycarousel_itemFirstInCallback(carousel, item, idx, state) { 
        display( idx +"<i> of </i>"+ $("#mycarousel li").length); 
    };
```

Comment: add this script in either script tag or in separate js file..
#myheader is the label in which you can see the counter... you do not need to add it in html..
you just need to create UL with ID mycarousel and respected LI inside it...
I hope this will be help full to you.. ask me for any further queries... :-)

Answer (score 0):

it is simple, just open the following file:

```
sites\all\modules\jcarousel\js\jcarousel.js
```

and in line 146:

```
carousel.pageCount =  Math.ceil(itemCount / carousel.pageSize);
```

change it to this: `carousel.pageCount =  Math.ceil(itemCount / 1);`

it will work superb :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)